# Could not find class file for introspecting factory methods: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.DiscardPolicy

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jboss, jboss6.x

Anyone, please help me to short out. 
While deploying my war file on Jboss it shows this below error. I stuck myself to find out what was the reason.

> [o.s.c.annotation.ConfigurationClassUtils] : Could not find class file
>   for introspecting factory methods:
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.DiscardPolicy
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource
>   [java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor/DiscardPolicy.class] 
>   ***cannot be opened because it does not exist***
>   at
>   org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:158)
>   ~[org.springframework.core-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar!/:3.1.0.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.(SimpleMetadataReader.java:45)
>   ~[org.springframework.core-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar!/:3.1.0.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:80)
>   ~[org.springframework.core-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar!/:3.1.0.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:101)
>   ~[org.springframework.core-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar!/:3.1.0.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:76)
>   ~[org.springframework.core-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar!/:3.1.0.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassUtils.checkConfigurationClassCandidate(ConfigurationClassUtils.java:69)
>   ~[org.springframework.context-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar!/:3.1.0.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:216)
>   [org.springframework.context-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar!/:3.1.0.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:178)
>   [org.springframework.context-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar!/:3.1.0.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:617)
>   [org.springframework.context-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar!/:3.1.0.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:446)
>   [org.springframework.context-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar!/:3.1.0.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:384)
>   [org.springframework.web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar!/:3.1.0.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
>   [org.springframework.web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar!/:3.1.0.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
>   [org.springframework.web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar!/:3.1.0.RELEASE]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3339)
>   [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar!/:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3777)
>   [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar!/:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]    at
>   org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:161)
>   [jboss-as-web-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar!/:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]  at
>   org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:59)
>   [jboss-as-web-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar!/:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]  at
>   org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:94)
>   [jboss-as-web-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar!/:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]  at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>   [na:1.8.0_74]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_74]
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   [na:1.8.0_74]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   [na:1.8.0_74]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_74]
>     at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
>   [jboss-threads-2.1.1.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:2.1.1.Final-redhat-1]

**Solution that I have found**

The problem with my configured spring bean ref injection.

***Before***

```
<bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor"> 
                    <property name="corePoolSize" value="100" /> 
                    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="50" /> 
                    <property name="queueCapacity" value="150" /> 
                    <property name="rejectedExecutionHandler" ref="discardPolicy" /> 
</bean> 
<bean id="discardPolicy" class="java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.DiscardPolicy"/>
```

***Modified (Solved)***

```
<bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor"> 
            <property name="corePoolSize" value="100" /> 
            <property name="maxPoolSize" value="50" /> 
            <property name="queueCapacity" value="150" /> 
            <property name="rejectedExecutionHandler"> 
                <bean class="java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.DiscardPolicy"/> 
            </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Just tell me what you did and what went wrong? just pasting a stacktrace won't help

Comment: @Shriram I'm trying to deploy my war file on Jboss 6.3.0. on deployment time, it shows this above message. Can you please help me to find out the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with configured spring bean ref injection.

```
<bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor"> 
            <property name="corePoolSize" value="100" /> 
            <property name="maxPoolSize" value="50" /> 
            <property name="queueCapacity" value="150" /> 
            <property name="rejectedExecutionHandler"> 
                <bean class="java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.DiscardPolicy"/> 
            </property>
</bean>
```